# Classroom API / Python : invitation().delete method not working

Tags: python

I have an issue on this python Google Classroom API to delete an invitation:

```
.invitations().delete(id = 'MTUyMTkzNjM3NjA2fDEwNDUzMjI5NTQxODcyMzE3MjcyN1pa')
```

The invitation ID is correct, but when I execute it, nothing happen : no error and no invitation deleted.
I have tested using Classroom API online with the ID, and it work : the invitation is deleted

I'm using the latest google python library :

```
google-api-core==1.22.1
google-api-python-client==1.10.0
google-auth==1.20.1
google-auth-httplib2==0.0.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0
```

Comment: Did you recreate it after online deleting?

Comment: I have create the invitation using the python API ; invitations().create(). which is working.
The invitation_id returned by this method is the parameter of the .delete() method.

Using this inviation_id as paramater, the deletion() does not work using python API, but do work using online API.